# RegEx HTML matching too much with lazy wildcard

Tags: html, regex, vbscript, regex-greedy, non-greedy

RegEx:

```
<span style='.+?'>TheTextToFind</span>
```

HTML:

```
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED <span style='font-size:18.0pt;'>TheTextToFind</span></span>
```

Why does the match include this?

```
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED
```

[Example Link](http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%3Cspan%20style=%27.%2b?%27%3ETheTextToFind%3C/span%3E&input=%3Cspan%20style=%27font-size:11.0pt;%27%3EDON%27T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED%20%3Cspan%20style=%27font-size:18.0pt;%27%3ETheTextToFind%3C/span%3E%3C/span%3E)

Comment: What language are you writing the regex in? More than likely there's an HTML parsing library for that language which would be [a more appropriate way of solving whatever problem you're actually having](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: vbscript is what I'm using the regex in

Comment: This is just a quick dirty regex to find some data. Obviously actually parsing the HTML is a better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex engine always find the **left-most** match. That's why you get

```html
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED <span style='font-size:18.0pt;'>TheTextToFind</span>
```

as a match. (Basically the whole input, sans the last `</span>`).

To steer the engine in the correct direction, if we assume that `>` doesn't appear directly in the attribute, the following regex will match what you want.

```
<span style='[^>]+'>TheTextToFind</span>
```

This regex matches what you want, since with the above assumption, `[^>]+` can't match outside a tag.

**However**, I hope that you are not doing this as part of a program that extracts information out of a HTML page. Use HTML parser for that purpose.

---

To understand why the regex matches as such, you need to understand that `.+?` will try to backtracks so that it can find a match for the *sequel* (`'>TheTextToFind</span>`).

```
# Matching .+?
# Since +? is lazy, it matches . once (to fulfill the minimum repetition), and
# increase the number of repetition if the sequel fails to match
<span style='f                        # FAIL. Can't match closing '
<span style='fo                       # FAIL. Can't match closing '
...
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;        # PROCEED. But FAIL later, since can't match T in The
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'       # FAIL. Can't match closing '
...
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'  # PROCEED. But FAIL later, since can't match closing >
...
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED <span style='
                                      # PROCEED. But FAIL later, since can't match closing >
...
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED <span style='font-size:18.0pt;
                                      # PROCEED. MATCH FOUND.
```

As you can see, `.+?` attempts with increasing length and matches `font-size:11.0pt;'>DON'T_WANT_THIS_MATCHED <span style='font-size:18.0pt;`, which allows the *sequel* `'>TheTextToFind</span>` to be matched.

Comment: I still don't get the "left most match". Can you elaborate on how it works?

Comment: @bradvido: Logically, you can think of the engine starting at index i, then it will exhaustively search for all substring starting at index i that matches the regex (the regex will determine the search order). If no match is found, then it will attempt at next index i+1. In this case, since it can find a match for the regex from index 0, it will return that match.